# Кавычки при повторе необычных сочетаний

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

В тексте встречается дважды сочетание "отходная пустынь":
*Отшельник устроил близ монастыря "отходную пустынь"...

Он часто уединялся в отходной пустыни*.

- Первый раз сочетание берется в кавычки, второй — без кавычек.
- **Вопрос:** надо ли по всему тексту использовать кавычки в этом (и в любом другом) сочетании или есть правило, по которому словосочетание единожды берется в кавычки, а впоследствии они просто опускаются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кавычки в такой ситуации могут понадобиться, чтобы обратить внимание читателя на особое (необычное) значение используемого выражения. Кавычки в подобных случаях используются факультативно. Отсутствие кавычек при повторах вполне оправдано — автор считает, что он уже акцентировал ранее внимание читателя на необычности термина.

Подробнее см. [правила использования кавычек](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1) на сайте Грамота.ру.

Answer (score 0):

В православной терминологии сочетания "**отходная пустынь, отходная келья**" не являются чем-то необычным, поэтому их лучше писать без кавычек.

Примеры:

**Отходная пустынь** (скит) Патриарха Никона рядом с монастырем тоже  располагался на крохотном островке. (СКИТ,  В православных монастырях: жилище монаха-отшельника, расположенное в некотором отдалении от монастыря).

Основной целью уединения подвижника **в отходной келье** является уход на безмолвие.  https://mospat.ru/church-and-time/669

Что касается **повтора необычных сочетаний**, то их лучше заменять синонимами, чем повторять в кавычках или без них.